# Excel Solver in Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, optimization, least-squares, minimization

I have a task to convert an Excel computation in Matlab for easier processing. The Excel document is using Solver to minimize a squared_error and I would like to implement this in Matlab. I have tried several options to no avail (I am getting unbounded issues with my attempted Matlab code), including fminunc. Here is the Excel logic that I am trying to replicate.

minimize sq_error (cell L8).
sq_error = a_0+a_1/C30^4+a_2/C30^3+a_3/C30^2+a_4/C30+a_5*C30

Where C30 contains a constant value for Normalized_pressure.

Excel is currently solving this by doing:
    SolverOk SetCell:="$L$8", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:="$A$7:$F$7

```
$A$7 = 10*a_0
$B$7 = 1000*a_1
$C$7 = 1000*a_2
$D$7 = 10000*a_3
$E$7 = 10000*a_4
$F$7 = 10*a_5
```

a_0 through a_5 are variables defined in Excel which just take the values in the cells $A$5 through $F$5 respectively.

My Matlab code trying to replicate this is as follows:

```
X_0 = ones(1,6);
fun = @(X) (10*X(1) + 1000*X(2)/norm_p^4 + 1000*X(3)/norm_p^3 + 10000*X(4)/norm_p^2 + 10000*X(5)/norm_p + 10*X(6)*norm_p);
[X, fval] = fminunc(fun,X_0);
```

This is not working. Any pointers? Also, fminunc requires an initial value for vector X (which I've provided here as just a ones vector). I dont know how Excel's solver decides the initial coefficient guess.

Thanks,
=D

Comment: The exact error message and runable code (what is `norm_p`?) that produces it would help others answer the question far more than "This is not working".

Comment: norm_p is a normalization constant (value of about 1.4). The error is as follows: 
Problem appears unbounded.

fminunc stopped because the objective function value is less than
or equal to the default value of the objective function limit.

<stopping criteria details>
@TroyHaskin

Comment: Understood.  In looking at the objective more closely, it is linear in the solution vector and, therefore, is unbounded from below.  If you wrap the objective in `abs()`, does MATLAB produce the same result as Excel?